# Are there graphics cards with throttling?

Tags: graphics-card, overheating

The pump of my water cooling system broke and it's great to see that the Intel i5 simply throttles and keeps working for 3 days now.

However, my monitor now started to blank out a few times and I wonder whether it's the graphics card which is running hot. It is connected to the water cooling system. I'm aware that I can probably not use it for 3D games, so I'm doing office work only.

Do most/all graphics cards nowadays have a throttling like CPUs have? Particularly, does the `RX480` have that? If graphic cards usually don't have that feature, are there models that do?

Comment: The cooler's broken... are you trying to break other things too?

Comment: That's what it sounded like... I'm thinking the real answer is to fix or replace the broken cooling system, rather than rely on software temperature monitoring to avoid catastrophic damage. (like gdi says +1)

Comment: I've ordered a new water pump, of course. It may arrive tomorrow. I just wondered whether graphics cards have such a feature.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turn off your computer. Without the pump, you're basically running your computer without any cooling. Nothing is moving the heated water away from the parts into the radiator to cool.

To answer your question. All graphics cards have various clock speeds they shift between based off use and temperature. I wouldn't be shocked if even at idle or low load clock speeds, your card was reaching dangerous temperatures. Water blocks are not effective passive cooling.